# Problems making a graphic in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I an working with ggplot. I want to desine a graphic with ggplot. This graphics is with two continuous variables but I would like to get a graphic like this:

[image]

Where x and y are the continuous variables. My problem is I can't get it to show circles in the line of the plot. I would like the plot to have circles for each pair of observations from the continuous variables. For example in the attached graphic, it has a circle for pairs `(1,1)`, `(2,2)` and `(3,3)`. It is possible to get it? (The colour of the line doesn't matter.)

Comment: show us some data, your current code and current output, please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# dummy data
dat <- data.frame(x = 1:5, y = 1:5)

ggplot(dat, aes(x,y,color=x)) + 
   geom_line(size=3) + 
   geom_point(size=10) + 
   scale_colour_continuous(low="blue",high="red")
```

Playing with low/high will change the colours.

In general, to remove the legend, use `+ theme(legend.position="none")`

Comment: this will remove *all* legends. But the former snippet will *only* remove that of the colour aesthetic. Maybe it doesn't hurt to show both.

Comment: Given the question, I think it will cause more confusion than it solves. KISS principle here. It's not exactly documented behaviour, but more of a trick.

Comment: Sorry, it *is* documented though. Check, for example, `discrete scale` in ggplot2 manual under the explanation for `breaks`.